# Why is my Vim build failing on WSL?

Tags: microsoft-windows, compile-vim, wsl

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 under WSL2 on Windows 11. I've cloned https://github.com/vim/vim.git in the environment. (The latest commit is tagged as v9.0.0260.) When I go to the directory and do this ...

```
./configure
sudo make
```

... the latter command reports:

```
/usr/bin/ld: objects/os_unix.o: in function `stop_timeout':
/home/me/git/vim/src/os_unix.c:8281: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
/usr/bin/ld: objects/os_unix.o: in function `start_timeout':
/home/me/git/vim/src/os_unix.c:8321: undefined reference to `timer_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/git/vim/src/os_unix.c:8334: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
/usr/bin/ld: objects/os_unix.o: in function `delete_timer':
/home/me/git/vim/src/os_unix.c:8349: undefined reference to `timer_delete'
```

A bit of searching shows that the problem might be related to the need for a -lrt flag somewhere in the build, to include the timer library. But I'm at a loss as to what changes the makefiles would need. The ./configure command doesn't tell me that I'm missing anything. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: See https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10831

Comment: @Matt: That was what I needed. I did "make distclean" followed by "./configure", etc., and the build worked. If you write up an answer, I'll accept it and give it a +1. Thanks!

Comment: Giving answer for your own question is welcomed on this site, so you can write it in all detail yourself.

Answer (score 2):

At [github.com/vim/vim/issues/10831](http://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10831) is this comment:

"Generally, after syncing to head, `make distclean` might be needed, because the configure checks may need to run again for changes in configure or build environment."

I ran: `make distclean`, after which the usual sequence of build instructions worked.

Thanks to @Matt for the insight.